# Visual Studio 2015 Not Showing Images and CSS Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to move from Visual Studio 2012 to VS 2015. In VS 2012 I don't have any problem, but in VS 2015, when I run my web site my image and my JavaScript code and styles are not loaded:in vs2012 when i click on website'images I see address //localhost:2323/template.... but in vs2015 localhost:2323 is omited and see //template...

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you have in Properties\Web tab?

Comment: thank you for your answer. when i click on image and get properties. I only  see General tab

Comment: I mean in VS2015. When you right click on the web project->Properties->Web tab

Comment: excuse me...I right click on my web site and I have two option 1- properties windows 2- property page . I click on both of them but not have web tab. I show images in both of them

Comment: I insert images in my question

Comment: I should say I have web site . I think web tab exist in web application type.is it correct?